# Java inheritance - constructors

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

While studying for my finals, I came across the following statement in the book from which I am currently studying. Considering the following code :

```
class A {
    public A(int x) {   }
}

class B extends A {
    public B(int x ) {   }
}
```

is it mandatory to call the constructor of class A in the constructor of class B(super(x)). The book states that it's not mandatory, because they have the exact number and type of parameters. But when I try this in a java compiler, the following error gets thrown :

> constructor A in class A cannot be
>   applied to given types;   required:
>   int   found: no arguments   reason:
>   actual and formal argument lists
>   differ in length

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The compiler automatically inserts `super()` in the beginning.

However, even constructors arguments, `super()` (without arguments) is added which invokes the *default* constructor of the superclass. And you don't have one, hence the error.

You have to specify `super(x)` (to invoke `A(x)`), or define a no-argument constructor.

By the way, Eclipse compiler gives a way better error message:

> Implicit super constructor A() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Comment: The error is thrown at this line : "public B(int x ) {}". The code that I posted in the question is all the code I am trying to compile (just the class definition, no instantiations at all).

Comment: It will only insert `super()`. It won't insert `super(int)`. Hence the error here. In this case, he does need to call `super(x)`. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html .

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the compiler tries to create a call to the superclasses default constructor with `super()`, which isn't avaliable:

```
required: int
found:    no arguments
```

But back to your book: I've never heard of a rule that you can skip the `super` statement in a constructor if the actual constructor has the exact same parameter list as a constructor in the direct superclass. Only a call to the superclass's default constructor is added implicitly (`super()`) but that requires that the superclass *has* a default constructor.

In contrast to what's written in your book (or in contrast to your understanding of the written text), here's a sentence from the language spec:

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation
>   and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then
>   the constructor body is implicitly assumed by the compiler to begin with a super
>   class constructor invocation **“super();”**, an invocation of the constructor of its
>   direct superclass that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a the base class having a default constructor (no-arg constructor), when you extend `B`, you don't need to explicitly call `super()` because it is called any way.

But when you have a constructor with arguments, when making the  contructor with parameters in `B`, you need to pass in `super()` a parameter for `A`

example :

```java
class A {
    public A(int x) {   }
  }

  class B extends A {
    public B(int x ) 
    {
       super(x); // need to specify the parameter for class A
       //... 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you dont have a default constructor and you are creating an instance with default one. Because If you have any Parameterized constructor then compiler will not insert the default one for you, instead you have to define.

Answer (score 0):

It is neccessary to call constructor of super class in case of Java. Therefore, whenever you generate constructor of sub class, super class' constructor is self created by IDE.

It is because whenever base class constructor demands arguments, compiler thinks they are to be filled by base class constructor. In case of default constructor, it is OK. No need to call super() in sub class.