# Understanding Inheritance in java

Tags: java

I was practising some of the inheritance concept which i have learned from my book although i haven't completely studied inheritance yet but i thought to just write a simple program based on inheritance here is it

```
public class InheritanceInJava
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       SupperClass_A supperObj_A = new SupperClass_A(20,30,10);
       SubClass_A subObj_A = new SubClass_A(10,20,30);
       System.out.println(subObj_A.Add());
       System.out.println(subObj_A.Multiply());
    }
}

class SupperClass_A
{
   int num1 ; int num2 ; int num3 ;
   SupperClass_A(int a, int b, int c)
   {
      num1 = a ; num2 = b ; num3 = c;
   }
  public int Multiply()
  {
     return num1 * num2 * num3;
  }
}

class SubClass_A extends SupperClass_A
{
  SubClass_A(int a, int b, int c)
  {
      num1 = a ; num2 = b ; num3 = c;
  }
  public int Add()
  {
      return num1 + num2 + num3;
  }
}
```

but it shows one error which is :

**constructor SupperClass_A in class SupperClass_A cannot be applied to given types;
    {
    ^
  required: int,int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length**

Can anyone help me understand why this program is not working and whats the cause for this error ?

Comment: since you declared a parameterized constructor in your `SuperClass_A` you have to call it from the Constructor in your SubClass.

Comment: (Correcting `SupperClass` to `SuperClass`) -- A `SuperClass_A` constructor has to be called when you make a `SubClass_A` instance, because every `SubClass_A` instance is also a `SuperClass_A` instance. Your `SubClass_A` does not specify what `SuperClass_A` constructor should be called (using `super(a,b,c)`), so the compiler assumes you want to call the no-arguments constructor. But there isn't a no-arguments constructor, so the compile fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java inheritance - constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248809/java-inheritance-constructors)

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that your `SubClass_A` constructor attempts to implicitly call a parameter-less constructor of `SupperClass_A`, which doesn't exist. A parameter-less constructor is generated automatically by the compiler only for classes that don't have any explicitly defined constructors.

You can fix it by calling the super class constructor explicitly :

```
class SubClass_A extends SupperClass_A
{
  SubClass_A(int a, int b, int c)
  {
      super(a,b,c);
  }
  public int Add()
  {
      return num1 + num2 + num3;
  }
}
```